# How to only call notifydatasetchanged() after x number of objects in x number seconds?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a listview with an adapter attached to it. I feed Message objects into the adapter. Usually I would just call notifydatasetchanged() after each addition, however I want to optimize it as sometimes I can get 10 messages going into the adapter in 2 seconds.

I tried the following code, but after a while the app would crash.

If additions are happening really quickly then I would like to only call notifydatasetchanged() every 4 additions. However if the addition rate is slower, maybe 1 addition per 2 seconds, then doing notifydatasetchanged() after each addition is fine.

Any ideas on how I would accomplish this? Thanks

```
    public void addMessage(Message message) {

        messages.add(message);

        count++;

        shouldwenotify();
    }


    private void shouldwenotify(){
        if (count == 1){
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1500);
        }

        if (count > 2){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            count=0;
        }
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count == 1) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                count=0;
            } else if (count == 2){handler.postDelayed(runnablesecond,  1000);}
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnablesecond = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count < 3) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you considered using `RecyclerView` in place of `ListView`? Then you can use the `notifyItemInserted()` and `notifyItemRangeInserted()` methods rather than having to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after each addition.

Comment: I did have a look into it, I think I decided not to go with it because you cant use transcript mode with recyclerview. There was also another reason but I cant remember what it was now. Maybe I will take another look. Thanks

Comment: I just implemented RecyclerView and it's working great now. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I implemented RecyclerView instead. It's much better for memory consumption and CPU usage.

The way I got it to scroll like a listview with transcript mode was to do this..

```
        if (dragging == false) {
            notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() + 1);
            list.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
        }

        list.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    dragging = false;
                }
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    dragging = true;
                }
            }
            });
```